# Pandas insert empty row at 0th position

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose have following data frame

```
        A   B   
1   2   3   4   5
4   5   6   7   8
```

I want to check if `df(0,0)` is `nan` then insert pd.series(np.nan) at 0th position. So in above case it will be

```
        A   B   

1   2   3   4   5
4   5   6   7   8
```

I am able to check `(0,0)` element but how do I insert empty row at first position?

Comment: care to explain down vote  guys?

Comment: I think it is a good question, this thread contains the only answer I found to a simple question I was looking for: append the last row: `df.loc[len(df)] = np.NaN`.  Ok for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) of `DataFrame` with one empty row:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns)
df = df1.append(df, ignore_index=True)
print (df)

     A    B    C    D    E
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
2  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

Comment: Where are you checking, (0,0) index is nan?

Comment: How come it got 3 more column? and why A and B shifted? sorry but got confuse.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - sorry, what is `print (df.head().to_dict())` of sample?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you can first append a row with zeros, shift the whole rows and overwrite the first with 0:

```
df
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  4  5  6  7  8

df.loc[len(df)] = 0

df
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  4  5  6  7  8
2  0  0  0  0  0

df = df.shift()

df.loc[0] = 0

df
     A    B    C    D    E
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
2  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```