# Pandas Dataframe to CSV, but writing n rows lower

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

Given a 3x3 dataframe, with index and column names to be included as a row/column themselves when converting the dataframe to a CSV file, **how can I shift the table down 1 row?**

I want to shift down 1 row, leaving 1 empty row to write to the CSV after using a completely separate list.

The code and comments below include more detail and clarity regarding my goal:

```
import pandas as pd
separate_row = [' ', 'Z', 'Y', 'X']

# Note: The size is 3x3
x = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
header_cols = ['a','b','c']
df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=[1,2,3], columns=header_cols)

# Note: Exporting as 4x4 now
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=True, header=True)

# How to make CSV file 5x4??
```

Row 1 in the CSV file will be filled by `separate_row`, though I cannot have `separate_row` as the column name when creating the dataframe. The column name MUST be `header_cols` but `separate_row` is to go above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136283/pandas-insert-empty-row-at-0th-position

Comment: The row must go above the dataframe header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    pd.DataFrame(columns=separate_row).to_csv(csvfile, index=None)
    df.to_csv(csvfile, index=True, header=True)
```

```
>>> %cat data.csv
 ,Z,Y,X
,a,b,c
1,0,0,0
2,0,0,0
3,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a newline to a file, then append the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# Note: The size is 3x3
x = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, index=[1,2,3], columns=['a','b','c'])



with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n')


df.to_csv('data.csv', index=True, header=True, mode='a')
```

Comment: It's not clear for me but I think the OP does not want a blank line, he wants the `separate_row`.