# Add empty rows at the beginning of dataframe before export to xlsx

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a pandas dataframe and I need to append 3 blank rows over the head of the columns before to export it to xlsx.

I'm using this code based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136283/pandas-insert-empty-row-at-0th-position):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(df.columns)], columns=df.columns)
df = df1.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

But it adds the rows at index 0 and I need the blank rows before the row with the column names in the xlsx.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startrow` parameter for omit first `N` rows:

```
N = 3
df.to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=N, index=False)
```